# Always use \othertailQ within italic text (kp-fonts)

Tags: kpfonts

I really like the long-tailed Q-shape kp-fonts has with the `oldstyle` option. However, I do not want the ct/st ligatures that this option provides, nor do I particularly want the long-tailed Q in upright text. Is there an option to automatically replace any letter Q by the long-tailed Q-shape (kp-fonts provides `\othertailQ`), *but only* within `\textit{}`?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable class
\usepackage{kpfonts} % Palatino clone (text and math)
\begin{document}
\scshape
Quo vadis \quad 
\othertailQ uo vadis \quad 
\itshape
Quo vadis \quad 
\othertailQ uo vadis
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've take the liberty of editing your query to post a minimum working example and an associated screenshot. Feel free to revert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're able to use either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, I suggest you do, as it'll enable you to use specials features of the OpenType version of the kpfonts. In particular, you can enable the "swashy" version of the letter `Q` for italics only, in both regular and smallcaps font shapes.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{KpRoman}[ItalicFeatures={Style=Swash}]

\begin{document}
Quid Pro Quo \quad \textit{Quid Pro Quo}

\scshape
quid pro quo \quad \emph{quid pro quo}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there any similar option for pdfLaTeX? I would like to use some of the microtype features that aren't available for XeLaTex/LuaLaTex.

Comment: @tolUene - "Is there any similar option for pdfLaTeX? " Not that I'm aware of; otherwise, I would have mentioned it in the  answer. I'm afraid I don't follow your microtype-related comment. For sure, viritually all microtype features available under pdfLaTeX are available under LuaLaTeX as well. (You are correct in pointing out, though, that most of `microtype`'s features aren't avaiblable under XeLaTeX.)

Answer (score 3):

Unicode version of KP fonts provide the `swsh` font feature which is independent from `dlig` font feature. The first one makes Q with long shape the second one makes st, ct ligatures. So, you need to set only `swsh` which can be done by `\swash` font modifier in OpTeX, for example:

```
\fontfam[kpfonts]
\def\it{\swash\_it}

Quo vadis, st. {\it Quo vadis, st, ct.} Query again in upright shape.

\bye
```